# event-calendar rails 4 doesn't work

Tags: javascript, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm tryong to use event_calendar gem and i follow this 3 guides 
    http://andolasoft.wordpress.com/2013/01/09/how-to-implement-event-calendar-in-rails-app/
    https://github.com/elevation/event_calendar#static-files
    https://github.com/elevation/event_calendar/wiki/Quickstart-from-scratch

I think that my problem is about the including of the stylesheet and of the javascript.
I can't understand the step of including because each guides say something different.

Heres the error

> TypeError in Calendar#index
>   Showing /home/user/work/aptana_1/spree_calendar/app/views/calendar/index.html.erb where >line #6 raised:
>
> no implicit conversion of nil into Hash
>   Extracted source (around line #6):

```
     <h1>Calendar</h1>

      <%= event_calendar %>

>Rails.root: /home/user/work/aptana_1/spree_calendar
>
>Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
>app/helpers/calendar_helper.rb:24:in `event_calendar'
>app/views/calendar/index.html.erb:6:in >`_app_views_calendar_index_html_erb___345437905_81942130'
>Request
>
>Parameters:
>
>{"year"=>"2014",
> "month"=>"07"}
```

and this is the calendar_helper file

```
module CalendarHelper
 def month_link(month_date)
    link_to(I18n.localize(month_date, :format => "%B"), {:month => month_date.month, :year => month_date.year})
  end

  # custom options for this calendar
  def event_calendar_opts
    puts("EVENTCALENDAROP")
    { 
      :year => @year,
      :month => @month,
      :event_strips => @event_strips,
      :month_name_text => I18n.localize(@shown_month, :format => "%B %Y"),
      :previous_month_text => "<< " + month_link(@shown_month.prev_month),
      :next_month_text => month_link(@shown_month.next_month) + " >>"    
      }
      puts"###{@year}"
      puts"###{:year.to_s}"
  end

  def event_calendar
    # args is an argument hash containing :event, :day, and :options
    puts "EVENT_CALENDAR"
    calendar event_calendar_opts do |args|
      event = args[:event]
      %(<a href="/events/#{event.id}" title="#{h(event.name)}">#{h(event.name)}</a>)
    end
  end 

end
```

and here is the view

```
<!-- Probably move the stylesheet to you layout. Also make sure you include the javascript. -->
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "event_calendar" %>

<h1>Calendar</h1>

<%= event_calendar %>
```

and here is the application layout

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>SpreeCalendar</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true ,'event_calendar'%>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The last commit to it was in 2011 and as a result appears to be only available for rails 2 and 3 - which you can see on the main github page of where you linked to.

Comment: do you think that it doesn't work for this reason?? do you know some gem for calendar handling? (not fullCalendar)

Answer (score 0):

the problem is within this method:

```
def event_calendar_opts
  puts("EVENTCALENDAROP")
  { 
    :year => @year,
    :month => @month,
    :event_strips => @event_strips,
    :month_name_text => I18n.localize(@shown_month, :format => "%B %Y"),
    :previous_month_text => "<< " + month_link(@shown_month.prev_month),
    :next_month_text => month_link(@shown_month.next_month) + " >>"    
  }
  puts "###{@year}"
  puts "###{:year.to_s}"
end
```

I believe the two calls to `puts` at the end are debugging output, but they change the return value of `#event_calendar_opts`. You should remove the `puts` or move them to the top:

```
def event_calendar_opts
  puts("EVENTCALENDAROP")
  puts "###{@year}"
  puts "###{:year.to_s}"
  { 
    :year => @year,
    :month => @month,
    :event_strips => @event_strips,
    :month_name_text => I18n.localize(@shown_month, :format => "%B %Y"),
    :previous_month_text => "<< " + month_link(@shown_month.prev_month),
    :next_month_text => month_link(@shown_month.next_month) + " >>"    
  }
end
```

Comment: I add that line for debugging but also without them  doesn't work. Do you know something about the step in wich the guide include the stilesheet and the javascript?